# Entity Print PDF stying issues

Tags: theming, 9

**How can I apply CSS styling to a PDF generated from node content?**

Using the [Entity Print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print) I am able to create PDFs from my node content.
My problem is the PDF output do not reflect the styling I am applying to it. For example, the **http://localhost:85/print/pdf/node/2** is the PDF url but it is entirely deviod of my styling despite my continued efforts.

Using the TCPDF (v1) pdf engine and having followed the pertinent instructions at this [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/entity-print/usage), I have the following configuration code:

In mytheme.info.yml:

```
entity_print:
  node:
    deal: 'oliverock/deal-pdf-styling'
```

And in mytheme.libraries.yml:

```
deal-pdf-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/deal.css: {}
```

And deal.css is quite simple:

```
* {
    color: red;
}

div {
    background: blue;
}
```

As I alluded to above, I expected that simple styling to take effect in my PDFs but it's all just black text on a white background.
And for the longest time I assumed my code was at fault until I noticed the **debug** line in the instructions.

All my code is visible at **http://localhost:85/print/pdf/node/2/debug** but that output is not a PDF.

I would appreciate some help please.

Comment: PDF conversion often takes print CSS into account. Maybe they're overriding your custom PDF code? Try more specific CSS and see what happens. Not all PDF converters understand all CSS. In my experience the best CSS support is in wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @prkos: Thank you for you suggestion which I tried but it raised new issues documented  here (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298148/phpwkhtmltopdf-engine-pdf-printing-configuration-issues). Can you help ?

Comment: @prkos: Now using the phpwkhtmltopdf engine but pdf is still not styled

Comment: Try using that engine without Drupal. Just make some dummy html file and call that converter script and see if you get a pdf. There's a lot of debugging steps to find out what might be happening...