# phpwkhtmltopdf engine pdf printing configuration issues

Tags: theming, 9

The screenshot below shows my Entity Print configurations for created styled PDFs from node content.
[image]

As shown in the screenshot I am using the phpwkhtmltopdf engine and the mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf package is installed via composer.

However, when I try generating the target PDF, the following errors results:

> Error generating document: Failed to generate PDF:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 1:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: cannot open
> ?php: No such file
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 2:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: namespace:
> not found /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 4:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: use: not
> found /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 6:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: /bin:
> Permission denied
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 7:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: INSTALL.txt:
> not found /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 8:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: INSTALL.txt:
> not found /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 9:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: INSTALL.txt:
> not found /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php:
> 10: /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php:
> INSTALL.txt: not found
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: 12:
> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: Syntax
> error: newline unexpected

I gave Pdf.php 777 permissions too.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /opt/drupal/vendor/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/src/Pdf.php: cannot open
> ?php: No such file

You need to install the missing library using composer

```
composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf
```

In addition, you might also need `h4cc/wkhtmltopdf`, see [Entity Print documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/entity-print/pdf-engine-support#s-composer-installation)

Comment: mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf was already installed at the time of my post. That's how I was able to trace the path to the Pdf.php script. What I'm concerned about is if the path I configured correct. I also installed the h4cc/wkhtmltopdf package as you suggested and using the same settings as before, the error continued to be an issue.

Comment: I was wrong about h4cc/wkhtmltopdf installing. I later notice it failed to install because there was no installation candidate. I had to use apt-get install wkhtmltopdf.
Also, the PDF engine path in the screenshot is incorrect. It sould be point to the path wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

[image: here]
The location has to be configured as per this picture